# NULL is not getting matched in case expression in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I want to write a query where for my date parameter 'P_D_IN_END_DT' if either '01/01/1900' or '01/01/1' or NULL is passed then i will take 'sysdate'  else i will take parameter i.e 'P_D_IN_END_DT' value only.

```
SELECT
     CASE
          WHEN  P_D_IN_END_DT IN ( TO_DATE ('01/01/1900', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),  TO_DATE ('01/01/1', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),  NULL)
          THEN
             TRUNC(SYSDATE)
          ELSE
             P_D_IN_END_DT
       END 
       AS END_DT
FROM DUAL;
```

For '01/01/1900' or '01/01/1' is working fine . But when i taking NULL in parameter then i am not getting sysdate rather i am getting NULL

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN NULL IN
                  (TO_DATE ('01/01/1900', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),
                   TO_DATE ('01/01/1', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), NULL)         
          THEN
             TRUNC(SYSDATE)
          ELSE
             NULL
       END
    AS END_DT
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Please tag only a **single** RDBMS... the one you are using... not multiple.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: I would try adding another WHEN to your CASE: `WHEN P_D_IN_END_DT IS NULL THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE)` and remove the NULL from your IN.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: Null is never comparably equal to anything. That's the problem.

Comment: `TO_DATE('01/01/1900','dd/mm/yyyy')` can be written more simply as `date '1900-01-01'`. It comes to the same thing but it's a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NULL is not equal to NULL; NULL is not un-equal to NULL. A comparison with NULL returns NULL.

Therefore:

```
SELECT
     CASE
          WHEN  P_D_IN_END_DT IS NULL
            OR  P_D_IN_END_DT IN ( 
             TO_DATE ('01/01/1900', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
          ,  TO_DATE ('01/01/1', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
          )   
          THEN
             TRUNC(SYSDATE)
          ELSE
             P_D_IN_END_DT
       END 
       AS END_DT
FROM indata;
```